# Moving image to back- and foreground over time

Tags: after-effects

I'm using Adobe After Effects. I have a composition with several layers. One layer consists of an image which is shown for around 20s. At time point 10s I would like to bring the image to the foreground (relative to the other layers) and at time point 15s I would like to move it again to the background.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After Effects by default works in 2D, but you can change a layer so that it can be moved in 3D space.  The layer itself is still flat, but (like a postcard moving through space) it can be positioned using x,y and z coordinates where z is depth.

This tutorial explains it well:
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/position-2d-layers-in-3d-space.html

You can also do full 3D work in After Effects, but I think this should cover your question.

Alternatively if you want to only work in 2D, sometimes I duplicate a layer, and have one layer at the bottom of my stack, and the duplicate layer at the top, so that when I need to change its apparent "depth", I make one layer invisible and make the other layer visible (by keyframing the Opacity property).